# RecycleView on calling onBindViewHolder() and onCreateViewHolder()

Tags: java, android

here is my code i dont know why its not working now songs is a simple java class which contains getter setters

Before fetching data from `JSON` i try to statically add data in recycleView and that was working perfectly fine.

> Here is code,

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_track, container, false);

        myOnClickListener = new track.MyOnClickListener(getActivity());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
        //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        loadData();

        return view;
    }
```

> code of JSON parsing using volley

```
  private void loadData()
    {
        String url = "http://homejobs.live/mydata.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try{

                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            Log.d("test", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
                            Log.d("test", String.valueOf(jsonArray.length()));
                            for(int i =0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                songs item = new songs(
                                        jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("name"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("uri")

                                );

                                Log.d("key", String.valueOf(item));

                                data.add(item);
                            }

                            adapter = new recycler_view_adapter(data);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("error"+error);
            }
        }

                );

                mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

> recycler_view_adapter class

```
public class recycler_view_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recycler_view_adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<songs> dataSet;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public static TextView textViewName;
        public static ImageView imageViewIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            this.imageViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        }
    }

    public recycler_view_adapter(ArrayList<songs> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(track.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder,  final int position) {
        Log.d("hy","test");
        songs songsData = dataSet.get(position);


        MyViewHolder.textViewName.setText(songsData.getName());
        System.out.println("hello"+position);

        Picasso.get()
                .load(songsData.getImage())
                .into(MyViewHolder.imageViewIcon);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Before : adapter = new recycler_view_adapter(data);...check data.size() in log.....

Comment: i tried not showing anything .. althrough it shows data in jsonObject.. what should i do now

Comment: So if data.size() is 0 then you should check your api response.

Comment: In the `onBindViewHolder` don't use `MyViewHolder` but `holder`

Comment: thanks issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

In your onBindViewHolder, change the following code

```
MyViewHolder.textViewName.setText(songsData.getName());
    System.out.println("hello"+position);

    Picasso.get()
            .load(songsData.getImage())
            .into(MyViewHolder.imageViewIcon);
```

to the following

```
holder.textViewName.setText(songsData.getName());
    System.out.println("hello"+position);

    Picasso.get()
            .load(songsData.getImage())
            .into(holder.imageViewIcon);
```

In  your code, you are trying to access the textview by using the class name. Instead you should use the `holder` variable.

Also please check whether you are parsing the json correctly. Check if the

```
data.add(item);
```

in the api response is getting executed. 
Another suggestion would be to check the size of your dataSet array in the adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing onBindViewHolder with this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder,  final int position) {
    Log.d("hy","test");
    songs songsData = dataSet.get(position);


    holder.textViewName.setText(songsData.getName());
    System.out.println("hello"+position);

    Picasso.get()
            .load(songsData.getImage())
            .into(holder.imageViewIcon);
}
```